# How can I prefix tables names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add a prefix to the tables names without change my class name?

```
dbo.Applications (Class Applications {})
dbo.Groups (Class Groups {})
dbo.Locations (Class Locations{})

dbo.Site1_Applications
dbo.Site1_Groups
...
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2005, .Net 4.0

Comment: Table names have nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. That is a framework for building web sites/applications. There are a number of technologies for accessing the database from plain ADO.NET to LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, and so on. Perhaps it is once of those frameworks you are asking about.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, I create a model (class) and when the application run the database is updated with the model in my project, but that table created in the database has the same name as the model, but I need to add a prefix...